# PHP data array variable not defined in view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, view

I am using codeIgniter and I am trying to pass an array of data. I have written like this:

```
$data['username']="Dumbo";
```

I also wrote this:

```
$data['shouts']=$this->Musers->getShout();  // retrieve data from table
```

Then I write:

```
$this->load->view("welcome_message", $data);
```

In view page, I wrote:

```
 <?php echo $username;
    foreach ($shouts as $shout)
        {
        echo $shout->shout;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $shout->timeStamp;          
        }
  ?>
```

Problem is that while the view did retrieve data from table and display results in view page, an error came up for `$data['username']` saying:

> "Undefined variable: username"

Why is that? The `$data['username']` is already defined! Or what did I do wrong?

Comment: "username" in $data['username'] is index, not variable.

Comment: @Maris this is the way codeigniter works you load an array to the view file and then you call the indexes as variables...@netrox I dont see any problem here, check you have all variable names and file names spelled correctly

Comment: does $data['username'] conflict with $data['shouts'] or what? I cannot figure out why it keeps saying $username is undefined but it has no problem with echoing the array of $shouts.

Comment: no it won't conflict with anything you can have as many $data variables as you like as long as they have different indexes, $shouts is not an array , $data is the array and shout is just the index that 'becomes' a variable in the view file...maybe you can try and post all of the code, you might get more help that way.Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $data['username']; ?>
```

If you wrote this, the error will occur.

Correct way is to write like

```
<?php echo $username; ?>
```

'username' is the index in the data array, which is passed to the view using the load method

```
$this->load->view("welcome_message", $data);
```

If you need to pass an array...

```
$data['usernames'] = $username_array;
$this->load->view("welcome_message", $data);
```

Then in the view,

```
<?php print_r($usernames); ?>
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I did. I updated. Still saying it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, do this..

```
$data = array(); 
$data['username'] = "something";
$data['shouts']=$this->Musers->getShout();
```

Comment: That's what I did. It was undefined.

Comment: Note: don't forget the $data = array();